# Laravel query taking long time to loads while if use the same query in Adminer its much faster

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following query i use in laravel controller:-

```
DB::select('SELECT status_id, COUNT(*) as row_count
FROM khatma_reads
WHERE khatma_id = 280881 AND khatma_id IS NOT NULL AND status_id = 2
GROUP BY status_id

');
```

it takes about 7 seconds to load.

While if i run the same query in Adminer SQL command, it takes only 0.049 seconds:-
[image]

I have tried to use the laravel Eloquent syntax:-

```
$khatma->reads->where('status_id',2)->count()
```

And

```
DB::table('khatma_reads')->select('status_id')->where('status_id',2)->where('khatma_id',$khatma->id)->count()
```

All taking almost 7 seconds.
I know Laravel is framework with different layers of checking, filtering .... and those functions can take time, but i don't think that they will slow the query response to more than 6 seconds.

Any advice.

Comment: How long does it take to load the Laravel page if you leave the query out? Mock it if the result is needed.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware less than a second

Comment: @Q8root `WHERE khatma_id = 280881 AND khatma_id IS NOT NULL` How can it be both at the same time? `WHERE khatma_id = 280881` should be enough.

Comment: you can use explain to check which part of query consuming more time

Comment: You can improve it 
`$khatma->reads()->where('status_id',2)->count()`
instead of using `->reads` since it loads the data into memory. I dont think its related to Eloquent, I think there's some issue in your app that loads the query really slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes it's not a query that is taking time but other processes that work behind it take time to respond.

For example,

- Here is one of my API response time (`115ms`) :
  [API Response Time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icE3a.png).
- and here is time taken by SQL queries (around `5ms`) :
  [time taken by SQL queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysZE6.png).

I would suggest using `Laravel Telescope` for debugging your queries (you can debug lots of other things like logs, jobs, requests, events, etc. as well )

Here is the official documentation of how to install and use the telescope -> https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/telescope.